# How to check which columns exist in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, exists

So I have a list of potential columns, and I know I can check if a certain column exists using.

```
SELECT null
  FROM user_tab_columns
  WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE' and column_name = 'MYCOLUMN'
```

How do I expand this to test multiple columns? i.e. Not sure what the exact syntax would be.

```
SELECT null, null, null
  FROM user_tab_columns
  WHERE table_name = 'MYTABLE' and column_name = 'MYCOLUMN' 
  or column_name = 'MYCOLUMN1' or column_name = 'MYCOLUMN2'
```

Comment: Couldn't  you use `DESCRIBE user_tab_columns`?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you're trying to do? What's the expected result here?

Comment: I basically just want it to print true or false depending on if the columns exist.  Im new to SQL and I guess Im trying to use what id do in python.

Comment: Where do you have the list of potential columns, in a separate table?

Comment: I have a text list generated in Python, I was gonna iterate through that to create the SQL statement

Comment: One way to iterate through your Python list is to assemble the potential column names into a factored subquery, like I illustrate in my answer. It is best if you are able to put everything into a single query and hit the DB only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I created a table with a single column, `column_name`. I test the existence of `column_name` in the table `EMP` in the `SCOTT` schema. I assume all table, column and schema names are already upper-case (since all catalog string values are upper-case), otherwise you will need case-insensitive comparisons. This example assumes the current user has access to the `SCOTT` schema (a standard schema found on most Oracle installations), and I use the table `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` instead of `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` (which only looks at the current user's tables).

```
with
     potential_columns ( column_name ) as (
       select 'EMPNO'   from dual union all
       select 'NAME'    from dual union all
       select 'MANAGER' from dual union all
       select 'DEPTNO'  from dual
     )
select p.column_name, 
       case when t.column_name is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end 
          as column_exists_in_table
from potential_columns p left outer join 
     (select column_name from all_tab_columns 
        where owner = 'SCOTT' and table_name = 'EMP') t
on p.column_name = t.column_name
;

COLUMN_NAME COLUMN_EXISTS_IN_TABLE
----------- ----------------------
EMPNO       TRUE 
DEPTNO      TRUE 
MANAGER     FALSE
NAME        FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code will be useful (I'm sure there must be a better solution):

```
select count(table_name) from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'YOUR_COLUMN';
```

For more than one colunm try this:

```
select count(table_name) from all_tab_columns where column_name in ( 'YOUR_COLUMN_1','YOUR_COLUMN_2')
```

This returns 0 if table not exists.

I hope will be useful for you

Comment: So if I have multiple columns Id want to test, how could I do it in one SQL statement?

Comment: @SharpObject I edited the answer, please try with the second example.

Comment: Cool, is there a way I can tell which ones don't exist? Since this just says how many exist

Answer (score 0):

Now you got the right answer,coming to Your query it would execute something like following, as `AND` has more precedence than `OR` in Oracle SQL.

```
SELECT null, null, null
  FROM user_tab_columns
  WHERE (table_name = 'MYTABLE' and column_name = 'MYCOLUMN')    <-- MYCOLUMN in MYTABLE
  or column_name = 'MYCOLUMN1'                                   <-- MYCOLUMN1 in ANYTABLE
  or column_name = 'MYCOLUMN2'                                   <-- MYCOLUMN2 in ANYTABLE
```